# Keras OOM. Smaller architecture run OOM while the bigger one not

Tags: keras

currently I'm on a semantic segmentation project and create a CNN architecture using Keras. I have 2 architecture, the first `model.summary()` result:

```
==============================================================================
Total params: 53,517,361
Trainable params: 53,499,089
Non-trainable params: 18,272
______________________________________________________________________________
```

And the second architecture `model.summary()` result:

```
=================================================================
Total params: 39,994,689
Trainable params: 39,973,569
Non-trainable params: 21,120
_________________________________________________________________
```

Both of them fed using same data, optimizer, and mini-batch size.
What really different is how i build the architecture.

At the first one i don't call any manually built function. So it's like:

```
down0 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(down0a_pool)
down0 = BatchNormalization()(down0)
down0 = Activation('relu')(down0)
down0 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same')(down0)
down0 = BatchNormalization()(down0)
down0 = Activation('relu')(down0)
down0_pool = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(down0)
# 128

down1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(down0_pool)
down1 = BatchNormalization()(down1)
down1 = Activation('relu')(down1)
down1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same')(down1)
down1 = BatchNormalization()(down1)
down1 = Activation('relu')(down1)
down1_pool = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2))(down1)
# 64
```

But on the second architecture I'm using manually built function for modularity.

```
def conv_batch_layer(x, layer_out, filter_size=3, padding='same'):
    x = Conv2D(layer_out, filter_size, padding=padding)(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    return x

start_layer_out = 32
conv_0 = conv_batch_layer(inputs, start_layer_out* 2**0) # 512 x 512 x 32
conv_0 = conv_batch_layer(conv_0, start_layer_out* 2**0)
conv_0_pool = MaxPooling2D(2)(conv_0) # 256 x 256 x 32

conv_1 = conv_batch_layer(conv_0_pool, start_layer_out* 2**1) # 256 x 256 x 64
conv_1 = conv_batch_layer(conv_1, start_layer_out* 2**1)
conv_1_pool = MaxPooling2D(2)(conv_1) # 128 x 128 x 64
```

Based on the summary, the first architecture is bigger than the second one. I train the model using a single GPU GTX Titan Xp 12GB. I encounter OOM when training the second architecture but not on the first one. Any suggestion what might be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference between your two models, **assuming that there have been called with the same input tensor**. What looks a bit suspicious and might cause the observed behavior is the fact that you are calling the first layer in the first version with `down0a_pool` while using `inputs` in the second. Are there both the same tensors, the same layers respectively?

Have you compared the layers of the both models, for example using `model.layers`?

Apart from this, the difference in parameters/memory footprint is just about 20% in your case. That's not very much and you might get rid of your OOM by just reducing the batch size a bit in case you shouldn't find the cause of the problem.

Comment: No, they are different at deeper layer. I'm using Conv2DTranspose at second architecture while the first one using only Conv2D layer. Do total params not enough to estimate the required memory?

Comment: So this means that the final models (stacked together) are different? Of course then you might end up with varying number of parameters. What Keras does to calculate this number is to iterate over all layers and and sum up the size of each weight matrix. You might therefore inspect this by yourself to confirm that there are different.